# JSF 1.2 to upgrade to the latest version / Update to latest jQuery version

Tags: user-interface, jsf, primefaces, richfaces, webui

I am facing an issue with my current application using JSF 1.2 version. As I am working on resolving some vulnerability issues, we need to update the application so that the jQuery is at 3.6.3 which is the latest one. It seems that RichFace 3.3.3 (current version) and PrimeFaces 1.1(current version) both have embedded jQuery on their own but they are not the latest ones.

I would like to know what dependencies I should change. I have update JSF 1.2 to 2.0 and the code doesn't break there. However, when I update PrimeFaces to 13.0.0, the application does not deploy. Same issue faced for RichFaces if I use the latest version.

Thank you and appreciate your guidance.

I updated the POM.xml dependencies using PrimeFaces 13.0.0 and RichFaces-API/RichFaces-Impl/RichFaces-UI to the latest ones and they don't work for me.

I am hoping for some guidances and step by step guide to update my code, ie JSF1.2 to the latest versions of PrimeFaces/RichFaces so that the embedded jQuery would be the latest one.

Comment: You might want to start here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0

Comment: It is really dangerous to try an upgrade the embedded Jquery versions of these JARS as JQuery has breaking changes.  Your better bet is to upgrade this app to newer versions of these libraries that include the latest jQuery.